# ¿Por qué no puedo usar el Nuget PhantomJS? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

He instalado el nuget PhantomJS en mi proyecto con Selenium y la instalación sale sin ningún error, pero las librerías de PhantomJs no me salen. Aquí les dejo imagenes de prueba.

Este es el selenium que tengo instalado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Phantom:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no puedo utilizar sus namespaces:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Guarda todo, cierra Visual Studio, abre nuevamente y revisa si el paquete de Nuget se ha instalado. En caso no se haya instalado, intenta instalarlo desde la línea de comandos con dotnet cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS ha sido removido a partir de la versión [3.14](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/CHANGELOG#L659):

> * Removed long-deprecated local PhantomJS support from .NET, as well as other deprecated code.

La última versión que soporta PhantomJS es la [3.13](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases/tag/selenium-3.13.0).

De la misma manera que instalaste la última versión de Selenium, abres el NuGet Package Manager, en el buscas y seleccionas el paquete. A la derecha te aparecerá un desplegable para elegir la versión que quieres instalar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como puedo descagar el nuget de esa version??

Comment: @LuisGarcia ya lo edité